# postgresql total of each column

Tags: postgresql

Does someone know in `postgresql` , how to obtain a sum of a sum ?

```
SUM(montant) OVER(PARTITION BY code_famille,texte_famille) AS montant
```

I tried this

```
sum(SUM(montant) OVER(PARTITION BY code_famille,texte_famille) AS montant) as total
```

Wrong syntax.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(montant) as total
from (
    select sum(montant) over(partition by code_famille,texte_famille) as montant
    from t
) s
```

But it makes no sense

Comment: Isn't that the same as `select sum(montant) from t`?

Comment: It can be more than that if `texte_famille` is not unique. But as I said it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I give you the correct answer:SELECT code_famille, texte_famille,
       COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY code_famille, texte_famille) AS nombre, 
       SUM(montant) OVER(PARTITION BY code_famille,texte_famille) AS montant,
       100 * SUM(montant) OVER(PARTITION BY code_famille, texte_famille) /SUM(montant) OVER() AS POURCENT_MONTAN,
       SUM(montant) over() as total_general_montant 
       FROM   public.examen 
ORDER BY montant DESC